# Combine line strips with different lengths?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

Right now I'm creating my OpenGL geometry objects - which all are wireframe models - this way (simplified code):

```
int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
element.shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(element.shaderProgram, m_gl3VertexShader);
glAttachShader(element.shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(element.shaderProgram);
glGetProgramiv(element.shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
glDeleteShader(m_gl3VertexShader);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &element.VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &element.VBO);
glBindVertexArray(element.VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, element.VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(centerCrossVertices), centerCrossVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(float),(void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
glBindVertexArray(0); 
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

Here centerCrossVertices is one GL_LINE_STRIP with a fixed length.

Later they are drawn this way:

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glBindVertexArray(m_gl3ElementList[i].VAO);            
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP,0,centerCrossVertices_size);
```

Now I want to display some more complex models which consist of several sets of line-strips but which have different lengths. Means there is one object which itself does not make use of one line strip but of several of them which can have different number of vertices they consist of.

My question: do I have to call the upper sequence for *each* of these line strips and do I need to create separate VBO/VAOs for each of them? Or is there a way to combine several line strips? If yes: how can this be done?

Comment: Note  the 2nd parameter of [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) is a index which specifies the first element of the buffer which has to be drawn and the 3rd parameter is the number of elements which should be drawn. So you can draw subsets of the array buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 this looks good - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to display some more complex models which consist of **several sets of line-strips** but which have **different lengths**

If you switch to an indexed draw-call (like [`glDrawElements()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml)) and use [primitive restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) you can render all your strips in a single draw-call.

Comment: According do the document you linked this requires at least OpenGL 3.1 while I'm limited to 3.0 - the answer given by @Rabbid76 in the comments above already solves my problem.

Comment: @Elmi: Ah, you didn't mention your version limitation anywhere, sorry.